# For a long running startup, getting 503 (site unavailable) on Standard Azure Website instance

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am using a small standard Azure Website instance with autoscale turned on.

My Asp.net application has to initialise (warm up, compile) some objects which take a little time, can be around 4 mins. I decided to do it up front rather than when a user hits the relevant code. However this setup seems to knock the Web instance offline with a 503 error, which is really surprising to me, since I thought Azure was very resilient. It is fine if it takes longer, and is subject to a bit of throttling, which one would only expected on Shared instances. Anyway 503 should not happen.

Any thoughts on how I can prevent this happening, except write more efficient code, which I am trying to do, but it cannot happen short term, so hoping for a Azure centric solution. In any case I am totally surprised that Azure Website "Standard" instance seem to throw 503s too easily, and become unavailable.

When I retry, after leaving for about 4 min, the site becomes available again, but my startup code will then return it to a 503 situation. When the startup code is implemented through the application when needed there is no issue apart from delaying the user. So code itself is not causing a problem, apart from running for a little while.

Thanks in advance,

EDIT: I think there is a 2 min limit in Azure Websites, which I may be exceeding

Comment: Obtain an error message. It will probably hint at the component that caused the 503. Probably, IIS/Azure think your site has failed. This is a very unusual situation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am running Elmah, and there is nothing obvious apart from the fact that the process takes a long time, and can be more than 2 mins. My current understanding is that if the process does take > 2 mins then it will timeout/cause numerous issues. I would have thought it should just quietly run on to completion, but perhaps I am misunderstanding something here. Perhaps long processes are automatically killed?

Comment: Also a 503 does look bad, like the site has been knocked out of action. It would be better for an exception to be raised and then an error page would be returned.

Comment: That's why I say find out who generates the 503. If it is the Azure LB you can either reconfigure it or you are definitely out of luck. If it is your website you might be able to use the normal ASP.NET timeout settings to increase the limit.

Comment: You should check your HTTP logs of your site and enable the failed request tracing in case your call is really crashing. If you have a long running call, eventually the request is cut off and 502 (not 503) is returned (but the request eventually finishes fine and you would see a success in the HTTP logs). 503 looks like a application crash. Also, if your warming-up call can actually send some content back in the meantime, it will help to keep the connection healthy. Those timeouts are only for idle connections (when no bytes are transferred).

Comment: I have now split up my long running process over a number of actions using redirects which keeps the Azure LB happy. The process now completes fine. Thanks all. In the fullness of time, I will sort the cause, again due to warmups but with some pretty involved Entity framework code.